# Is there a Stack Exchange site for tools, materials and manufacturing?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have questions about tools, materials and how to manufacture certain objects. Is there any SE site where I can ask such things?

For example, I've bought [a wire used like a cable tie](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Alambre_de_Hierro.jpg). On the package it says "Iron Binding Wire" and "Alambre de Hierro". Searching for this text on the internet finds something else than what I've bought. I wanted to ask what's the correct name for this material. I am thinking about tools and materials used mainly in woodworking, plumbing, metalworking and constructions. And the kind of tools that everyone have in their house - like pliers, hammers, screwdrivers.

Comment: It really depends on what you're manufacturing, for example, https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, https://diy.stackexchange.com/, https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/, https://aviation.stackexchange.com/, https://space.stackexchange.com/, 
 https://physics.stackexchange.com/, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ etc. Unfortunately Metalworking proposals and CAD proposals have both repeatedly failed. Can you give a little bit more detail to narrow down the scope?

Comment: Thanks. Well, for example I've bought [a wire used like a cable tie](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Alambre_de_Hierro.jpg). On the package it writes "Iron Binding Wire" and "Alambre de Hierro". Searching for this text on the internet finds something else than what I've bought. I wanted to ask what's the correct name for this material. I am thinking about tools and materials used mainly in woodworking, plumbing, metalworking and constructions. And the kind of tools that everyone have in their house - like pliers, hammers, screwdrivers..

Comment: I have no idea in which category this wire fits though. It can be used by anyone in their house to arrange their cables. As for the professionals, maybe the electricians and the guys who bring you internet, cable tv and telephone to your house are using it. That's why I was looking for a site about tools and materials, in general.

Comment: @Fructibus Where I'm from, NYC, we call that a *twist-tie*. Google *twist-tie spool*. You'll find them in any hardware store.

Comment: @Dan Bron - Thanks, [that's the correct name for it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twist_tie). So it would be nice to have a SE site to ask such basic questions about generic materials and tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your example, I believe https://diy.stackexchange.com might be appropriate for such things, especially if you can frame it in a home improvement context. Browse through their [tools tag](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools) and have a look at some of the well-received questions. Be sure to also read [their topic guidelines](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and don't be afraid to ask on [their meta](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com).

As for tool and manufacturing questions in general it really just depends on the specific case. For example:

- https://woodworking.stackexchange.com if you're asking about woodworking tools, materials, and techniques.
- https://electronics.stackexchange.com if you're building electronics or have a question about materials in an electrical engineering context.
- https://diy.stackexchange.com for construction and home improvement topics.
- https://mechanics.stackexchange.com for motor vehicle topics and engine theory.
- https://aviation.stackexchange.com for aircraft topics and theory.
- https://space.stackexchange.com for spacecraft topics and theory.
- https://physics.stackexchange.com for questions about specific physics.
- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com for questions about chemical properties of materials and such.
- Etc. My little description blurbs are vastly oversimplified but in general check tags and site metas.

Unfortunately, Metalworking and CAD proposals consistently fail in Area 51, so there are no sites dedicated to those two topics.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jason C's excellent answer, its worth remembering that "guessing game" questions - aka "what is this thing" questions rarely do well on SE. While there's some sites that *do* ID questions (based on text) - this style of question is hardly searchable.

In this *specific* case DIY.SE would be the right place.

*However* a question of this sort would need to be optimised for searchability.

For example

> I have a roll of wire similar to a twist tie, which I am using to tie
> my cables to my desk. It consists of thin gauge wire in insulation
> with a bit of overhang on either side of the wire. It comes in a small
> roll similar to this [image]
>
> What would this be called?

Would likely work better

Personally I prefer velcro cable ties ;)

Answer (score 0):

For this and similar questions, I think either [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) or [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) could be appropriate, depending on whether you're a native speaker and whether the term is something you would expect native speakers know and take for granted that everybody knows.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answers https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/ could be relevant too.