# How did this reopen review happen before its edit?

Tags: support, review, edits, vote-to-reopen

Concerning this question:

- [Is there a Stack Exchange site for tools, materials and manufacturing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296424/is-there-a-stack-exchange-site-for-tools-materials-and-manufacturing)

And this edit:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/296424/4

And this review:

- https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/50943

I had edited the question then voted to reopen it. Then, unrelated, I was checking out the review history and noticed the question had a recent reopen review, so I took a look.

What I discovered was this review, which indicated that it happened 8 minutes ago and showed my edit:

> [image]

But at that point in time I had made the edit only *2* minutes ago, that is, the review happened 6 minutes *before* the edit it displayed:

> [image]

AFAIK, edits to closed questions put the question in the reopen review queue. So, given that that appears to be the case here, what happened here? How did the review happen 6 minutes before the edit was made or, if the review was unrelated to the edit, why is it showing the revision from 6 minutes in the future?

<s>I'm tentatively tagging [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) for now, although I may just be misunderstanding something.</s>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I believe this played out:

As we can see from your revisions screenshot, the OP of that question edited a single word a while before you made your edit. This would have triggered the reopen review, as I recall that it's the *first* edit after the closure that does so.

The reviewer then reviewed it 6 minutes before you opted to edit. They saw revision 3 of the question, as that was the most current revision of the post.

When you edited, the review updated to show the *new* most current revision of the post.

This actually makes sense: If the review didn't update from showing revision 3 to revision 4, reviewers would not be voting to reopen based on the current state of the question. I would bet if the reviewer went back to look at their review, they would also see your edit of the question.

Comment: This is the answer. The review task was created ~18 minutes after the OPs edit, but the task will always display the most recent edit.